# laravel one to many relationship, is blade optimized?

Tags: php, laravel

Consider this blade code:

```
@if ($job->user->from_country)
<span class="flag"><img src="images/flags/{{ $job->user->from_country }}.png" /></span>
@endif
```

a job has user, user has multiple jobs, this relationship lives in model.

Now I wonder if I've 2 times in blade template: $job->user->from_country is it being queried in db 2 times?

What if I'm accessing other parameters of user, like username etc, are those queried separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user object will be cached and not again queried from the DB.
If you are inside of a loop (multiple `$jobs`) I also highly recommend you [eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) the user relation

```
$jobs = Job::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->with('user')->paginate(9);
```

...so there will be only one query for all user objects for each job model.

And finally, you can also use this syntax (It doesn't perform any better but I personally like it more)

```
@if($from_country = $job->user->from_country)
    <span class="flag"><img src="images/flags/{{ $from_country }}.png" /></span>
@endif
```

Comment: How do I eager load user with job in this case?
$jobs = Job::orderby('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);

Comment: accessing user, in case of eager loading will be same? $job->user->key ?

Comment: You can just add the `with()` statement anywhere in your query (I updated the answer with your code) Also accessing the relation is exactly the same :)

Comment: is there difference between putting with() before orderby or not?

Comment: No it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Thanks! You are answering all my laravel questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Once you call `$job->user`, the whole user object will be cached, so no worries.

This has nothing to do with blade. This is all Eloquent's doing.

Comment: @salivan in the worst case just try it! activate the query logging in mysql and just do it. that will show you if there is an overhad..